# EC2, bottle.py connection

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bottle

Not able to launch a bottle.py server using an EC2 Ubuntu Linux 12.04 instance with a public IP address.  The program (hw.py) is from the bottle tutorial ie.

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello world'

run(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=80)
```

Run as:

```
> python hw.py
or
> sudo python hw.py
```

generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw.py", line 7, in <module>
    run(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=80)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 2700, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 2382, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The EC2 public IP address is not attached to any other process.  Port 80 is not attached to another process.

```
> sudo netstat -lp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      629/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      629/sshd
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 463/dhclient3
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7190     667/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5888     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7312     741/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     26855    21843/udevd         /run/udev/control
```

Changing to: run(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=8080)

The error is socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address.

Changing to: run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

... which binds the server to all IPs/interfaces.  Typing the EC2 public IP address into browser with and without :8080 displays a "This page is not available".

Ideally, the first option ie. run(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=80) should work as that is how other web servers are kicked-off.  Anyone have ideas how to solve this one?

EDIT: added last set of lines from strace -f:

```
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/Socke"..., 70  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
) = 70
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23321, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f434cbfe000
read(4, "\"\"\"Generic socket server classes"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "service) is to maintain an\nexpli"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "set()\n\n    def shutdown(self):\n "..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "n't use serve_forever()\n    - fi"..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4    )                     = 4
write(2, "self.socket.bind(self.server_add"..., 38self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
) = 38
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f434cbfe000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/socke"..., 57  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
) = 57
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20485, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f434cbfe000
read(4, "# Wrapper module for _socket, pr"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "oo long.\"\n    errorTab[10064] = "..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4    )                     = 4
write(2, "return getattr(self._sock,name)("..., 39return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
) = 39
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f434cbfe000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "socket", 6socket)                   = 6
write(2, ".", 1.)                        = 1
write(2, "error", 5error)                    = 5
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "[Errno 99] Cannot assign request"..., 42[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address) = 42
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f434c7d1cb0}, {0x41d920, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f434c7d1cb0}, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: Have you tried running Python as root?

Comment: > sudo python hw.py gives the Cannot assign requested address error.

Comment: Run with `strace -f`, paste relevant bits before the error.

Comment: added last set of lines before error. thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. I use it for testing the network.

```
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Service Running'

run(
        app,                    # Run |app| Bottle() instance
        host     = '0.0.0.0',
        port     = 8080,
        reloader = True,        # restarts the server every time edit a module file
        debug    = True         # Comment out it before deploy
        )
```

Run this file (hw.py) at background of your server:

```
$ cd path/to/your/file
$ nohup python server.py &
```

Then I think you can visit now.

---

> Changing to: run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
>
> ... which binds the server to all IPs/interfaces. Typing the EC2 public IP address into browser with and without :8080 displays a "This page is not available".

Case of this error, I think you need to visit with `/hello` at the end of your root URL.

Comment: Tried but didn't work.  First, the connection to EC2 using public IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) does work because I'm testing with another Python web server and that connected.  But, bottle.py doesn't work.  Also tried with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/hello and that doesn't work either.  Tried both Chrome and FF - no luck!

Comment: @dbv You can try `$ ps aux | grep hw.py` to check whether it is running or not. And b.t.w, are you sure that you've opened the port for your service?

Comment: opened 0.0.0.0:8080 port through EC2 and it now works.  thanks!  btw, do you know why bottle.py doesn't bind with the EC2 public IP address at port 80 in hw.py ie. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80?  also, does this limitation apply when the standard bottle server is replaced with say, a multi-threaded server?

Comment: @dbv I think you need to open port 80 at your AWS console panel.

Comment: the other web server being tested uses port 80 and so was already open. my guess is that an ip:port combination is available when the standard bottle server is replaced.

Comment: @dbv Might servers be conflicted with each other?

Comment: the other web server and its dependencies are all stopped/shutdown before testing on bottle.

Comment: @dbv that's weird. Have you tried other ports except 8080, like 8888? Of course you need to open it first. Take a try if you'd like to. ;)

Comment: opened ec2 port 8888. run(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=8888) didn't work. run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888) did work. yep, it is weird.